# proof of wellposedness for heat equation in tempered distribution

Tags: partial-differential-equations, distribution-theory

It is well-known that the Cauchy problem for the heat equation
\begin{align}
&\partial_t u-\Delta u =f\\
&u|_{t=0}=u_0, \  \text{and} \  f \in\mathcal{S}'
\end{align}
has a unique solution in $C([0,+\infty);\mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R}^d))$, where $\mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R}^d)$ is the class of tempered distributions.

How can we prove this?